# Different font sizes in nested HTML list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have created a nested `ol li` list class in CSS  for my website but there is some mistake due to which each `li` is displayed in different `font-size`. although I have defined the `font-size` to it.

```
 .number_list ol {
       font:normal 1.2em 'Arial' ,Helvetica; 
       text-align:justify;
  }
 .number_list li{
      list-style:decimal;
      list-style-position:outside;
      font-size:1.2em;
  }
  .number_list ol li{ 
      list-style:lower-alpha;
      list-style-position:outside;
      margin-right:5px;
      font-size:1.2em;
  }
  .number_list ol li ol li {
      list-style:lower-roman;
      list-style-position:outside; 
      margin-right:5px;
      margin-top:5px; 
      font-size:1.2em;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because you are using `em`, you can use  `rem` instead.

`em` is equal to the size of the font that applies to the parent of the element in question. instead `rem` is applied to root of the element.

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

> **em**
>
> This unit represents the calculated `font-size` of the element. If used on the `font-size` property itself, it represents the inherited
>   `font-size` of the element.
>
> This unit is often used to create scalable layouts, which keep the vertical rhythm of the page, even when the user changes the size of
>   the fonts. The CSS properties `line-height`, `font-size`, `margin-bottom`
>   and `margin-top` often have values expressed in em.
>
> **rem**
>
> This unit represents the font-size of the root element (e.g. the `font-size` of the `<html>` element). When used on the font-size on this
>   root element, it represents its initial value.
>
> This unit is practical in creating perfectly scalable layout. If not supported by the targeted browsers, such layout can be achieved
>   using the `em` unit, though this is slightly more complex.

```css
.number_list ol {
  font: normal 1.2rem 'Arial', Helvetica, text-align:justify;
}

.number_list li {
  list-style: decimal;
  list-style-position: outside;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.number_list ol li {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.number_list ol li ol li {
  list-style: lower-roman;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="number_list">
  <ol>
    <li>test a</li>
    <li>test b</li>
    <li>test c</li>
    <li>test d
      <ol>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `em` unit, when used in a `font-size` declaration, denotes the font size of the parent element. Thus, you are cumulatively setting the size larger and larger in nested elements.

To have the same font size within the entire element, simply set it on the outermost element only. This means keeping your `font:normal 1.2em 'Arial' ,Helvetica;` rule and removing the `font-size` rules (or changing them to `font-size: 1em`, but this is needed only if some other CSS rules may set the size on them).

Answer (score -1):

The 'mistake' is that you are using `em`.

> “Ems” (em): The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document
>   media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the
>   font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt. Ems are
>   scalable in nature, so 2em would equal 24pt, .5em would equal 6pt,
>   etc. Ems are becoming increasingly popular in web documents due to
>   scalability and their mobile-device-friendly nature.

From: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

In short, you are setting each sub-element's font size 120% bigger than the one before it.
To fix it, just set a font size using an absolute unit - such as `pt`.

You may refer to this CodePen for an example: https://codepen.io/masterdoctor/pen/GmJEbN?editors=1100

Comment: Why downvote? Could you please explain what's wrong with the answer?