# Getting unexpected output when tried to markup h1 inside i tag inside h1 tag

Tags: html, css

I am Having little confusion for the output I am getting while I tried the following code:

```html
<h1>something</h1>

<h1>
  <i>
    <h1>something</h1>
  </i>
</h1>
```

As you may see the output generates text with font size much bigger than usual h1 tag, Can you please suggest any reason for it or any mistake I have made in it?

Comment: Why would you put one H1 inside another H1? It's invalid HTML and makes no semantic sense either.

Comment: Additionally, you can't put an `h1` inside an `i`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different font sizes in nested HTML list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439190/different-font-sizes-in-nested-html-list)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screenshot of DOM inspector]

The default font size of `h1` (in my browser at least) is `2em` which means it is double the font size of the parent element.

Since you have nested the headings, the first one doubles the font size from the body, then the second one doubles the result.

---

You could change this by overriding the default font size with CSS. However, HTML forbids the nesting of H1 elements, so you should change the HTML instead. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/). Write valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

While that's certainly invalid HTML and serves no semantic purpose, the explanation has to do with the definition of `em`, the unit of font size being applied. Simply put, an `em` unit is the width of the `m` character at the current font size. Therefore, because your browser applies a font size of `2em` for each level 1 heading element, the value is doubled. The inner heading has twice the font size of the outer.